# Why do I get an automatic crash as soon as I boot up into Unity?

Tags: kernel, chromebook

Why do I get an automatic crash as soon as I boot up into Unity?

```
$ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/focal...
dbus[10824]: Unknown username "whoopsie" in message bus configuration file

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 4.14.277-19080-gea2f6526b6dc #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jul 17 19:39:27 PDT 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure drm.trace=0x106 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 5767168 verity payload=PARTUUID=43e53ec1-0972-784e-a584-2d27bf3b1e1f/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=43e53ec1-0972-784e-a584-2d27bf3b1e1f/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=5767168 alg=sha256 root_hexdigest=5c801cd079f824f962ae960d96ee373b10001fa32c7d5d59470f20226da0b8e3 salt=d21543438d95f9cf691f414db8c5c56964d0e305db7ecb44c51831c8af794967" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=43e53ec1-0972-784e-a584-2d27bf3b1e1f add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 gsmi.s0ix_logging_enable=1 intel_idle.slp_s0_check=1  
Build Date: 06 July 2022  01:53:24PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Sat Aug  6 21:53:01 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.LibCrosService was not provided by any .service files
method return time=1659840782.082497 sender=:1.43 -> destination=:1.487 serial=14516 reply_serial=2
   boolean true
error: Kernel is too old for Iris. Consider upgrading to kernel v4.16.

(II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
crouton: version 1-20220111101058~master:a9eafaee
release: focal
architecture: amd64
xmethod: xorg
targets: unity
host: version 14816.131.0 (Official Build) stable-channel octopus 
kernel: Linux localhost 4.14.254-19080-gea2f6526b6dc #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jul 17 19:39:27 PDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
freon: yes
Running exit commands...
/usr/bin/xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down Hangup
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.LibCrosService was not provided by any .service files
method return time=1659840788.847275 sender=:1.43 -> destination=:1.489 serial=14524 reply_serial=2
   boolean true
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/focal...
```

If it is my kernel, how do I upgrade to 4.16 without being able to access the terminal in Ubuntu?

Comment: @nmath you can tell from the xorg version and the release info they're on Focal.  however it's on a Chromebook so it's possible OP is using a chrome kernel because it's a chromebook, and Ubuntu needs far newer than their chromebook provides.

Comment: Crouton is heavily outdated. You can dual boot Ubuntu with ChromeOS https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466